# how to get the selected values of all radio buttons on submit in php?

Tags: php

i am developing online  test application,dispalying all the question in one page with options.how can i get all selected value of radio buttons on submit with the question id.

```
<?php
include_once('connect.php');
$sql="select * from testquestions where testid='126'";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
$data = array(); // create a variable to hold the information
while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) !== false)
{
 $data[] = $row; // add the row in to the results (data) array
}
//shift off the first value
array_shift($data[0]);

 $merge = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $data);

 $size=sizeof($merge);
 $newdata=array();
 $num=1;
 echo "<form action='fetchquestion.php' method='post'>";

 foreach ($merge as $key => $value ) 
 {

 $sql2="select qid, question,option1,option2,option3,option4 from question where qid='$value'  ";

  $result2=mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());


   while($row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
            {
              $questionid=$row2['qid'];
             $question=$row2['question'];
             $option1=$row2['option1'];
             $option2=$row2['option2'];
             $option3=$row2['option3'];
             $option4=$row2['option4'];
               $newdata[]=$row2;



             echo '<div><div class="question">';    
             echo "$num<h3>$question</h3>";

             echo "</div>
             <div class='answer'>
             <ul>
             <li><input type='radio' class='radioBtnClass' name='option' style='width:50px'  value='1'/>$option1</li>
             <li><input type='radio' class='radioBtnClass' name='option' style='width:50px' value='2'/>$option2</li>
            <li><input type='radio' class='radioBtnClass' name='option' style='width:50px' value='3'/>$option3</li>
            <li><input type='radio' class='radioBtnClass' name='option' style='width:50px' value='4'/>$option4</li>
            <input type='hidden' name='count' value='$num' id='count'>

             <input type='hidden' name='queId' value='$questionid' id='queId'> 
           </ul></div></div>";
         $num++;
           }



                  } 
                  echo"<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'><br>
                    </form>

                  ";    
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $_SESSION['quiz'] = array();
               // get rid of the submit element in the $_POST

              unset($_POST['submit']);
                // assign the values of the radio buttons to the $_SESSION['quiz'] array
              $_SESSION['quiz'] = $_POST;
                  echo "submitted form";
                    }
                   else { 
                echo "Please submit the form.";
                       }



                    }
                 else
              {
                     echo " no questions available for selected test";
                     }
                   ?>
```

how can i achieve this?
could anybody help?

Comment: Is it One question per page? How do you know that the options are for the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "</div>
             <div class='answer'>
             <ul>
             <li><input type='radio' class='radioBtnClass' name='option_$questionid' style='width:50px'  value='1'/>$option1</li>
             <li><input type='radio' class='radioBtnClass' name='option_$questionid' style='width:50px' value='2'/>$option2</li>
            <li><input type='radio' class='radioBtnClass' name='option_$questionid' style='width:50px' value='3'/>$option3</li>
            <li><input type='radio' class='radioBtnClass' name='option_$questionid' style='width:50px' value='4'/>$option4</li>
            <input type='hidden' name='count' value='$num' id='count'>

             <input type='hidden' name='queId[]' value='$questionid' id='queId'> 
           </ul></div></div>";
```

After form submit use this code

```
   $data = $_POST;
   $que_array = $data['queId'];
   foreach($que_array as $key => $value){
        $que_id = $value;
    $option = 0;
    if(isset($data['option_' . $que_id])){
        $option = $data['option_' . $que_id];
    }

        echo $que_id . "--" . $option. "<br>";
   }
```

Comment: thanks,i am getting array of the question ids but am not getting the selcted radio button values.i am getting only the last selcted values.

Comment: did you change form code <li><input type='radio' class='radioBtnClass' name='option[]' style='width:50px'  value='1'/>$option1</li>

Comment: yes,its giving error undefined offset 1,undefined offset 2 for $key

Comment: its storing only value of offset 0,

Comment: Need one more help,how can i store value zero if no radio button selected with question id?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using name of radio button as array.

So to get value of selected radio use this code :

```
    echo $_REQUEST['option'][0];
```